# Arc Length Parametrisation

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Let $x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be given by 
$$
x(t) = \left(\frac{2}{(t^2+1)} -1, \frac{2t}{(t^2+1)}\right)
$$
Find the arc length parametrisation of {$x(t) : t\in[a,b]$}.

Now, I have found 
$$
v(t) = \frac{2(1-t^2)-4t}{(t^2+1)^2} \implies \|v(t)\|=\sqrt{\frac{(-2t^2-4t+2)^2}{(t^2+1)^4}}
$$
But the problem is I don't know how to integrate $\|v(t)\|$ from $0$ to $1$.

Am I going about this the wrong way or can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: It seems hard to integrate, although the result is elementary; see [the result from WolframAlpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B-2t%5E2-4t%2B2%7D%7B%28t%5E2%2B1%29%5E4%7D%7D+)

Comment: $v(t)$ should be a vector function, just like $x(t)$. You have a scalar there.

Comment: I am not sure that your derivatives are correct. Could you tell what you obtained ?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\dot x(t)=\left(\frac{-4t}{(t^2+1)^2},\frac{-2t^2+2}{(t^2+1)^2}\right).$$
The numerator of its squared norm is 
$$16t^2+4t^4-8t^2+4=4(t^2+1)^2.$$
Now I'm pretty sure you'll take it from here.

Edit: observe that $\|x(t)\|^2=1$, hence $x(s)=\bigl(\cos(s),\sin(s)\bigr)$ is the desired parametrization.